# Does displacement current occur in an inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, induction, displacement-current

We have learned in school that displacement current comes about due to a change in electric field flux per time in a capacitor (Ampere-Maxwell Law). Does the same displacement current come about in an inductor for the same reason?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever electric field or polarization changes in time, the displacement current is present. If electric current in wire that makes up the inductor changes in time, electric field will change as well and there will be displacement current.

Comment: Isn't the current generated by a time-varying auxiliary field in a inductor a free current? That is, I believe it's represented by the current $\mathbf{J}_F$ in $\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J}_F + \partial \mathbf{D}/\partial t$, and that $\partial \mathbf{D}/\partial t$ (the definition of displacement current) is zero.

Comment: @LucasBaldo No, real current isn't "generated by" displacement current. These are different concepts of current.